# How to prepare the data so that I can count results by lowest selected hierarchy?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 4 dropdowns in the frontend, each representing a hierarchy level in the company:

```
Groups > Units > Departments > Teams
```

So users can select a group then it will only show units of that group and departments of that group and so on..

But users can also select multiple choices so they can select Group1, Group2, and it will show all the corresponding hierarchy "items".

I let the users select however they want - they can choose any department, any group and team and so on.

The goal is to count the number of results from the lowest of each selected hierarchy.

Example:

| id | username | group | unit | department | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t1 |
| 2 | user2 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t2 |
| 3 | user3 | g3 | u6 | d12 | t30 |
| 4 | user4 | g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 |

The way I currently do it is to clean the selections so if for example a user clicked `g1>u1>d1` and `g25>u54>d70>t88`, I build it with query builder like so:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $myQuery->orWhere(function($query) use ($filter) {
        foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {
            $query->where($column, '=', $value)
        }
    }
}
```

So the the raw SQL query would result in this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (group='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1')
OR WHERE (group='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88')
```

But I need to return the count for each, not the actual results.

I could do something like the following using `UNION`:

```
SELECT group
     , unit
     , department
     , NULL as team
     , COUNT(*) AS rows
  FROM table
 WHERE group='g1' 
   AND unit='u1' 
   AND department='d1'
GROUP
    BY group
     , unit
     , department
UNION ALL
SELECT group
     , unit
     , department
     , team
     , COUNT(*) AS rows
  FROM table
 WHERE group='g25' 
   AND unit='u54' 
   AND department='d70' 
   AND team='t88'
GROUP
    BY group
     , unit
     , department
     , team
```

But I am not sure I can convert it do work with Query Builder.

Also, I feel like maybe the entire way I organize the data or build the initial query is wrong for the purpose.

Should I arrange the data differently completely? Or there is a way to achieve what I'm trying in this way?

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you can do something like this:

```
// prepare a query to operate with
$countQuery = DB::table('table');

// I don't know how do you get those filters, let's pretend it's like this
foreach ($filters as $index => $filter) {
    // make a count subqueries for every bunch of filters and name it like filter0, filter1 etc.
    $countQuery = $countQuery->addSelect(["filter".$index => 
        function ($q) use ($filter) {
            $q->selectRaw('COUNT(table.id)')
                ->from('table');
            foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {
                $q->where($column, '=', $value);
            }
        }]);
}

var_dump($countQuery->get());
```

Comment: Thank you I'll test it soon. And if it helps, the filters come as array of arrays: Thank you I'll test it soon. And if it helps, the filters come as array of arrays: `[['group' => 'g1', 'unit' => 'u1', 'department' => 'd1'] , ['group' => 'g25', 'unit' => 'u54', 'department' => 'd70', 'team' => 't88']]`